# Check input argument for optional prefix

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash script and I need help.

My script will receive 3 input arguments. One of them may have (doesn't have to) a `-v` or `-n` modifier, for example:

```
$1="-v image"
```

How can I check what mode an argument has?

I could write something like

```
tmp=$(echo "$1" | grep "^-v")
```

for each option and each argument, then check whether `tmp` is empty. But it is like brute force and I don't like it. Could you help me?

Comment: Use `getopts` instead.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about it. I think it will help

Comment: If your script is invoked as `script -v image foo bar`, then it receives 4 arguments.  If it is invoked as `script "-v image" foo bar`, then it gets only 3.  Are you really requiring your user to quote their arguments like that?

Comment: What do you mean by "mode"?

Comment: tripleee, I meant some option, so my script will do different functions depending on this option. I don't know how to name it in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
case $1 in
    (-v\ *) arg=${1#-v+([[:space:]])}; mod=v ;;
    (-n\ *) arg=${1#-n+([[:space:]])}; mod=n ;;
    (*) arg=$1; mod=;;
esac
echo "mod: $mod"
echo "arg: $arg"
```

call this snippet `banana` and `chmod +x banana`. Then:

```
$ ./banana '-v image'
mod: v
arg: image
$ ./banana '-n    image'
mod: n
arg: image
$ ./banana 'image-v'
mod:
arg: image-v
$ ./banana '-vimage'
mod:
arg: -vimage
```

Answer (score 0):

A more concise alternative, using bash's regex-matching operator, `=~`:

```
# Assumes that $1 is the argument of interest and that it contains something like
# '-n val', '-v val', or 'val'; $mode will receive the option letter only, if any.
mode='' arg=$1 
[[ $1 =~ ^-([vn])\ *(.*)$ ]] && mode=${BASH_REMATCH[1]} arg=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
```